# Does anybody recognise this language?

Tags: lua

```
function myObject:new ( x, y ) 
    local object = {} 
    setmetatable ( object, myObject )   
    self.__index = self 
    self.mX = x 
    self.mY = y 

    return object  
end
```

Does anybody recognise the above language?  I am using a custom scripting language developed by a vendor of ours, but I believe the language is based on a more widely known language base, with some of their add-ons on top.  Not being very aware of scripting languages, I don't recognise the above, but would very much like to get a language reference document if one exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be [Lua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29)